# How to left out join two big tables effectively

Tags: mapreduce, google-bigquery, apache-spark-sql

I have two tables, table_a and table_b,
table_a contains 216646500 rows, 7155998163 bytes;
table_b contains 1462775 rows, 2096277141 bytes

table_a's schema is: c_1, c_2, c_3, c_4 ;
table_b's schema is: c_2, c_5, c_6, ... (about 10 columns)

I want to do a left_outer join the two tables on the same key col_2, but it has run for 16 hours and hasn't finished yet... 
The pyspark code is as follow:

```
combine_table = table_a.join(table_b, table_a.col_2 == table_b.col_2, 'left_outer').collect()
```

Is there any effictive way to join two big tables like this?

Answer (score 0):

Beware of exploding joins.

Working with an open dataset, this query won't run in a reasonable time:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM `fh-bigquery.reddit_posts.2017_06` a
JOIN `fh-bigquery.reddit_comments.2017_06` b
ON a.subreddit=b.subreddit
```

What if we get rid of the top 100 joining keys from each side?

```
#standardSQL
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (
  SELECT * FROM `fh-bigquery.reddit_posts.2017_06`
  WHERE subreddit NOT IN (SELECT value FROM UNNEST((
  SELECT APPROX_TOP_COUNT(subreddit, 100) s
  FROM `fh-bigquery.reddit_posts.2017_06`
)))) a
JOIN (
  SELECT * FROM `fh-bigquery.reddit_comments.2017_06` b
  WHERE subreddit NOT IN (SELECT value FROM UNNEST((
  SELECT APPROX_TOP_COUNT(subreddit, 100) s
  FROM `fh-bigquery.reddit_comments.2017_06`
)))) b
ON a.subreddit=b.subreddit
```

This modified query ran in 70 seconds, and the result was:

```
90508538331
```

90 billion. That's a exploding join. We had 9 million rows in one table, 80 million rows in the second one, and our join produced 90 billion rows - even after eliminating the top 100 keys from each side.

In your data - look for any key that could be producing too many results, and remove it before producing the join (sometimes it's a default value, like `null`)

Comment: Thanks Felipe. This is a good idea for join, but not for left out join. But thanks anyway:)

Comment: more context -> more specific answer ;)

Comment: yes, I add "left out join" to the question's title:)

Comment: the issue is not the size of the data (which is detailed in the question), but the shape of it - is this a 1:1 join, a 1:many join, an exploding join? did you try limiting the most common keys as shown in the answer?

Comment: I need to get all the keys from table A. So limit to the most common keys is not work for me. I try to do some transformation to the key from string to int, hope this will make it work fast.

Comment: I know what you want, but in order to debug this issue, we need to try some stuff. If you don't give me more information, I can't give you more advice.

Comment: I solved the problem by restarting my cluster... And it take 8 hours to do the joining now:) Although it is still quite a long time. But it is acceptable:) Thanks Felipe anyway:)

Comment: Restarting cluster? Why is this question tagged "BigQuery"? If BigQuery is not being used for this join, try it out - may resolve your problems in seconds instead.

Comment: Do you mean read data from bigtable? It hang without progress while I am reading the raw data from bigtable...  Finally I change to read from the raw file in storage instead, and create a TempView to do join instead