# BigQuery speed - time from __SHUFFLE1_REPARTITION0

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to understand why a BigQuery query takes so long.

There are a couple of posts about interpreting the output of `Explanation`, but couldn't find anything out there to help understand what's going on in this case.

Any thoughts on why reading from `__PSRC___SHUFFLE2_0` and writing to `__SHUFFLE2_REPARTITION0` would take so long? Is this repartitioning by a new key? (Though the prior step, 13, was also written by `HASH($290)`

This currently takes about 200s on a *sample* of our data, of which 70% is spent on this step.

(I can't post the whole query here, though I could post a redacted version if helpful.)

[image: Query Timing]

Comment: Stage 2 and stage 5 are interesting. Stage 2 goes from 2M rows to 7M and, stage 5 gets 10 M rows with an output of 140M. I suspect exploding joins. How large is the size of the data queried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avoid exploding joins.

Without much more context, I can't tell what's happening, but stage 2 and 5 are interesting:

- Stage 2 goes from 2M rows to 7M
- Stage 5 gets 10 M rows with an output of 140M.

I suspect exploding joins. How large is the size of the data queried?

Without further data I'll say that I'm happy that BigQuery can handle exploding joins like these, but I wouldn't expect extremely fast queries when doing exploding joins.

For a concrete example of exploding joins, take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/46533335/132438.

Comment: OK, thanks. Stage 2 is an `UNNEST` and Stage 5 is a `JOIN`, which I'll investigate.

Comment: Do you know why all the time would be spent on the Shuffle & Repartition if it's an exploding join? Why wouldn't the expense come from the join itself?

Comment: BigQuery looks at the number of rows the query is going to scan and decides to give 100 slots to this job. Suddenly this query is going over 10000x times more rows, and more nodes are needed (exploding join). To put those nodes to work, BigQuery has to re-shuffle and re-partition all the data in flight. That's why this becomes the slow step.